# How to add sequelize getter to model object?

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I would like to add getter to **name** field of the Company model object.
tried several things but no luck.
Unable to find a proper example as well.
Sequelize version is 5.21.
Would it be inside decorator or somewhere else?
Trimmed code for clarity.
Any help is appreciated

```
    export default class Company extends Model<Company> {
      @PrimaryKey
      @Default(DataType.UUIDV4)
      @Column(DataType.UUID)
      id: string;
    
      @Default(DataType.NOW)
      @Column
      created_at: Date;
    
      @Default(0)
      @Column
      deleted_at: Date;
    
      @AllowNull(false)
      @Column(DataType.STRING(25))
      name: string;
    
      @Default(true)
      @Column
      active: boolean;
    
      
    }
```

Comment: Look at https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-typescript/issues/832#issuecomment-700965957

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `VIRTUAL` type of a column along with a getter and a setter:

```js
@Table({ modelName: 'application' })
export class Application extends Model<Application> {

  @Column(DataType.VIRTUAL(DataType.STRING))
  get clientSecret(): string {
    return this.getDataValue('clientSecret')
  }

  set clientSecret(value: string) {
    this.setDataValue('clientSecret', value)
  }
}
```

See [this comment in an issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-typescript/issues/832#issuecomment-700965957)